# swift 3.0 query in json search value return pair associated

Tags: json, swift3

I have just spent hours trying to understand how a JSON works. I give up, can you guys help me out?

Here's what I need. I have a local JSON that looks like this:

```
[
     {
       "partnumber": "1",
       "description": "part#1"
     },
     {
       "partnumber": "2",
       "description": "part#2"
     },
     {
       "partnumber": "3",
       "description": "part#3"
     }
]
```

and I am trying send a query to that JSON if `textfield.text ="1"` return the value of description.

I can open the file and parse it but I am stuck there

```
private func readJson() {
        do {
            if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "convertcsv", withExtension: "json") {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                if let object = json as? [Any] {

                // what to do here ???????????
                print(object)

                } else {
                    print("JSON is invalid")
                }
            } else {
                print("no file")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

I have seen that we can filter the JSON, would it work in that case or do we have to use a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JSON only contains strings so this should works :

```
private func readJson() {
    do {
        if let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test", withExtension: "json") {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: file)

            if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String:String]] {

                for array in jsonResult {
                    if array["partnumber"] == "1" {
                        print(array["description"]) // part#1
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("JSON is invalid")
            }
        } else {
            print("no file")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Probably not the cleanest way to do it, you might want to use some library (SwiftyJSON...)

Comment: Thank you TagTaco, this was easier than I thought!!